# What is the maximum memory available to an application on 64-bit Windows

Tags: c++, .net, windows, memory

I am getting this question all the time from my users, unfortunately I have not found good links about x64 (x86 is a different story).

What is the maximum memory available to an application on 64-bit Windows:

1. C++ application
2. .Net application
3. .Net application using C++ libraries
4. Application is running on [Windows 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)/2012 server
5. Application is running on Windows 7/8

Comment: As much memory as you have for the time being...

Comment: More than you will ever need, or the size limit on the page file. Whatever comes first.

Comment: _"What is ..."_ - what have you found yourself? Like [Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: 16 Tb of total virtual memory.8Tb for a process. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294418 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300794.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is: "Hey, John, you forgot another delete in that destructor!" - "Nah, don't worry, we're shipping as 64 bit."

Comment: +CodeCaster, well I've seen those limits, it states 4gb for 32-bit, in fact I am quite sure that a single application can get only up to 2Gb and somehow not always. I expect something similar for 64-bit as well

Answer (score 1):

The total amount would be - in theory - a bit over 18 quintillion (2^64 or 18 billion billion) bytes or 18 billion gigabytes assuming addresses are considered to be unsigned. If you limit yourself and consider a signed 64 bit integer, then you're looking at half of that. Oh, and don't forget to subtract memory that's going to be reserved for hardware, like video ram, address space for busses, etc.

But even these numbers aren't necessarily the maximum (at least theory wise), because there are additional tricks you're able to pull off (like using physical address extension to use more than 2 GB on 32 bit).

So, essentially as the short answer: 64 bit allows you to address and use all the memory your money can buy.

Unfortunately there are most likely hardware and software limits that are much lower, for example the maximum amount of memory being useable by your mainboard (depending on the age of the board, right now would usually be 8 or 16 GB, sometimes 32 GB). [Judging by Windows itself, the maximum amount can vary greatly, based on your architecture and version you're running.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the link you gave me is the exact one I found. And telling the truth I expect some additional limits from microsoft.

Comment: There's no real reason for even more limits (other than those mentioned). The issue of old 32 bit programs being limited to 2 GB rather than 4 GB (as you might expect with 32 bit address space) is a legacy issue of them using signed integers at first.

Comment: Well if you check the links, you will know that max amount of ram available to any windows system is 2Tb which is much less then theoretical max.